# How to Import Intellisense files into vsCode (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: node.js, express, javascript-intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure I understand how the intellisense works for Microsoft's new vsCode text editor.  In the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/nodejs) under the *"Great Code Editing Experience"* heading, it shows a warning under the node global variable `__dir` and offers a lightbulb suggestion to add a reference to a d.ts file so you can get intellisense for node:

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1 - How do I import [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/) files (d.ts) directly (without editor suggesting it) or do I have to copy them from the github source and put them in a typings directory?

2 - Can I get intellisense for any library that has a typescript definition?  I tried the below, but when I type in `express.` or `when.` , I don't get any intellisense.  However, I do get node intellisense.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../typings/express/express.d.ts" />

var when    = require('when')
  , express = require('express')
  , gulp    = require('gulp')
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

UPDATE: August 2016: TSD is now depreciated. instead use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings

```
npm install typings --global
```

OR

If using VS2015 NodeJS v1.2 released 29th July 2016 then typings-core@1.3.1 is installed automatically for you during first use:

```
Executing command 'npm install "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\NODE.JS TOOLS FOR VISUAL STUDIO\1.2\TypingsAcquisitionTool"
ntvs-typings-acquisition-tool@1.0.0 ..\..\..\..\..\node_modules\ntvs-typings-acquisition-tool
├── minimist@1.2.0
└── typings-core@1.3.1 (array-uniq@1.0.3, thenify@3.2.0, zip-object@0.1.0, popsicle-status@2.0.0, popsicle-retry@3.2.1, listify@1.0.0, promise-finally@2.2.1, xtend@4.0.1, graceful-fs@4.1.5, throat@3.0.0, lockfile@1.0.1, strip-bom@2.0.0, sort-keys@1.1.2, string-template@1.0.0, make-error-cause@1.2.1, any-promise@1.3.0, has@1.0.1, rc@1.1.6, object.pick@1.1.2, debug@2.2.0, mkdirp@0.5.1, invariant@2.2.1, configstore@2.0.0, parse-json@2.2.0, touch@1.0.0, detect-indent@4.0.0, is-absolute@0.2.5, popsicle-proxy-agent@3.0.0, rimraf@2.5.4, popsicle@8.0.4, typescript@1.8.7)
```

-----Original Answer-----

#### There is a package manager for Typescript Definition Files.  This is a community driven repository containing Typescript definitions for many popular libraries.

You can install tsd by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd).

Once you install tsd globally, you can install packages from your project root in the command line like this:

```
$ tsd install express --save
```

This will create a typings directory if one doesn't exist and adds an express directory with an `express.d.ts` file inside.

[image: Screenshot]

It also creates a `tsd.d.ts` file that contains the references to all of your tsd files.  If I install a few more tsd's, here is what it looks like.

[image]

Now to access my tsd files, all I need to do is reference their path in at the top of my code with `/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />`

[image]

Now I get intellisense.

[image]

Comment: Im sorry but this does not answer the question though. I'm having the same issue and using TSD. When using TypeScript it seems there's no way to get intellisense for modules imported using the syntax "var xxx = require('yyy');". The intellisense only shows up when using the syntax "import xxx = require('yyy');" but then the resulting generated JS contains a "define(...)" function that does not exist... (not to mention the "require" keyword does not show up in blue color as shown in the screenshot).

Comment: @rama intellisense is working fine for me with the `var xxx = require('yyy');` syntax.

Comment: not working for me for some reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282551/vscode-autocomplete-on-express-methods

Comment: Is there a way to automatically reference them, or do I always need to add this to the top of my file?

Comment: "/// References for .d.ts

With the introduction of jsconfig.json, you no longer need to use /// references in each file. As the file set is defined in jsconfig.json, VS Code knows what files and symbols are part of your project." https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson

Comment: I tried the npm install typings --global solution - but still not getting any jquery intellisense....

Answer (score 16):

In Jan'2016 "tsd" package was deprecated. Use "typings" package instead.

See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269

And you could find in VS Code (ext install) two extentions - *Typings Installer* and *Typings* which helps to install d.ts definition files easily from VS Code.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the `jsconfig.json` file after the April 2017 release.

Sample content of the file:

```
{
 "typeAcquisition": {
     "include": [
         "jquery",
          "underscore"
     ]
   }
}
```

See the `jsconfig.json` reference for VSCode [here.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)

Comment: What is the reason for the down vote here? This looks totally valid according to the docs (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition).

Answer (score 3):

Check if you are working in **Explicit Project mode** (REF: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson)

### What is happening?

In the **Explicit Project Mode**, VS Code uses "main.d.ts" files under the typings folder for intellisense. This file will have reference to other definition files and hence the intellisence works perfect. In my case, the main.d.ts looks like the following

```
/// <reference path="main/ambient/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/express/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/serve-static/index.d.ts" />
```

In the **File Scope Mode**, VS Code will not check for the typings definitions and hence no intellisence. In such case to add intellisence, the reference tag will come handy as you are referring the definition manually. If you are referring manually, refer the main.d.ts under the typings rather than going for definition for a specific library. This will make your code less reference dense.

Also note that the typescript equivalent for **jsconfig.json** is **tsconfig.json** which will also set the editor to Explicit Project mode.

Answer (score 1):

I got express intellisense to work with express by downloading the `express.d.ts` file from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped, and referencing it with a path relative to my project dir:

```
/// <reference path="express.d.ts"/>
```

I'm still trying to find what `/typings` refers to. It might also be nice to configure `d.ts` files as part of project settings.

**Edit:**

Found it.

```
~/Downloads/VSCode-osx
▶ find . -type d -name "typings"
./Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/applicationinsights/Scripts/typings
```

So they have `node`, `async`, and `applicationInsights` bundled into the OSX .app by default. Anything else you want I guess you can simply include as I did above.

**Edit Edit:**

The [tsd package manager](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) mentioned by @kurtcorbett looks nice, use that.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to automatically install the type definitions for your packages, you could download the [Types auto installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jvitor83.types-autoinstaller) extension. It will watch your `package.json` and `bower.json` and automatically install types for you.

I think the best part about this extension is that you don't have to include the `/// reference` lines in your code because it installs the types through npm.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was touch the lightbulb and chose the option that said add reference to node/node.d.ts to the proyect.

After that I just wrote: /// at the top of the editor and it worked for me.

Comment: The lightbulb does not appear when I create a type in a .js file in a vs code project.