# How can I install a TypeScript definition file so it is always loaded by VS Code?

Tags: sharepoint, typescript, visual-studio-code

I do a lot of work with SharePoint, so I would love to be able to install the [SharePoint and Ajax typescript definitions](https://github.com/gandjustas/sptypescript) files so I can have Intellisense for them in VS Code.

I found this other question here on SE:

[How to Import Intellisense files into vsCode (Visual Studio Code)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29975036/988264)

but it deals with OSX (I'm on Windows), and apparently you still have to add references at the top of your code files.

Is there a way / place I can install them so that VS Code automatically loads them always and I do not have to reference them at the top of my code files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do what I originally wanted, which is have the type definitions loaded whenever I started Code, no matter where I was working.

So the answer is to do something similar to what Nypan suggested, but it turns out it's even easier than that.

According to the [documentation on the VS Code website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript), I don't even need a `tsconfig.json` file, I can use a `jsconfig.json` file, and I don't even need to specify the type definition files in the "files" section.

> As an example, you can just drop a new type definition .d.ts file into
>   your project folder and VS Code will pick it up automatically.

So, I just have to have the `.d.ts` files somewhere under the "root" of my workspace, and a `jsconfig.json` file in the root that is as simple as:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

and with that I get the IntelliSense for the SharePoint stuff.

Comment: An empty jsconfig.json file works for me. And the typescript declarations don't have to be in the root of the project, I have them in a /types directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a tsconfig.json file ([read more about it here](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json)) and place it in the root of your "project".

Something like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "out": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "myDefinition.d.ts",
        "myOtherDefinition.d.ts",
        "SomethingToTranspile.ts",
        "SomethingElseToTranspile.ts",
    ]
}
```

The above is just an example, read more about it at the link i provided.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition

If you are using Visual Studio Code 1.8+, one alternative is to explicitly list packages to acquire type declaration files for in your jsconfig.json.

```
"typeAcquisition": {
    "include": [
        "lodash"
    ]
}
```