# vscode autocomplete not working on methods in typescript

Tags: autocomplete, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am code with `vscode` using `typescript`.
Everything working perfect except I do not have an autocomplete on methods in my `app.ts` however if I open app.js which is automatically generated file so I can see no issues with autocomplete there.

Here is my `app.ts`

```
/// <reference path="./typings/tsd.d.ts"/> 
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
```

Then on typing first word I am getting autocomplete on it

[image]

But after I type `.` vscode is not giving any `app.` `Request.`

[image]

I have all `td` installed.
My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "watch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there any way to fix that?

Yes. Instead of :

```
var express = require('express');
```

You should use `import/require` :

```
import express = require('express');
```

## Docs

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html