# Visual Studio Code: Intellisense not working on Mac

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

Tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975036/how-to-import-intellisense-files-into-vscode-visual-studio-code) and various other suggestion on SO.
My typings structure:
[image]

I can't get any intellisense to work. Using my reference path `/// <reference path="typings/main.d.ts" />` from the root directory (aka the path is correct from the file location).

Would using Node Version Manager (NVM) affect typings global install and Visual Studio Code's use of it? Any hints or suggestions to debug on how to get intellisense to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Removing NVM and installing plain Node. Restarting Vscode. Allows intellisense to work.