# Adding autocomplete / Intellisense from js file without importing it in vs code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an JS sdk, which the users aren't using require to load it in their JS script.
I'd like to offer intellisense / autocomplete of the SDK in VSCode, without requiring the user to do any difficult actions except installing an extension or setting something easy in jsconfig.

They have a js module with the SDK in a path other than the workspace.
I've checked the following solutions:

1. snippets - but it doesn't support auto complete object properties
2. custom type definition - since it's not in the workspace. It doesn't load it (especially since the script is not doing a `require` or `import` statement)
3. Language server - seems over the top

Any suggestions?

---

Following this [How to Import Intellisense files into vsCode (Visual Studio Code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975036/how-to-import-intellisense-files-into-vscode-visual-studio-code) , I've done the following:

1. added the following into my `jsconfig.js` but it didn't affect the autocomplete at all:

   ```
   "typeAcquisition": {
   "enable": true,
   "include": [
       "C:\\test.d.ts"
   ]
   ```

   }
2. Once I added `/// <reference path="C:\test.d.ts" />` it was resolved

Is there a way to automate this using an extension? or avoid requiring the reference path at all?

Comment: I just added a answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73161485/7475099), it should be relevant to what you have asked above.